# Android - Fullscreen activity API 14 (Android 4.0)

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen

I need to create full screen activity that works on API 14 (Android 4.0). I'm using this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

It's not working. I haven't seen any crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(0x10);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

But I think that should work, and your version. If you swapped

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

[image]

Comment: Please use text instead of screenshots for ease of copy/paste.

Comment: There was his code. I just showed the order of the blocks.